# Why is the Android browser NOT hiding URL bar after scrolling?

Tags: javascript, android, html

The internet says window.scroll(0,100) will hide the URL bar, if one is allowed to scroll down. However, NO address bar is hidden via code on Android chrome. Any ideas?

```
<!doctype html>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<div class=one>hello<div>

<style>
  body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
  }   
  .one{
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    color: white;
  }
</style>
<script>
  window.onload = ()=>{
    window.scrollTo(0, 100)
  }
</script>
```